# trouble changing font with URxvt

Tags: terminal, fonts, rxvt

I'm trying to change fonts in URxvt.

```
$ fc-match "FuraCode Nerd Font Mono"
Fura_Code_Regular_Nerd_Font_Complete_Mono.otf: "FuraCode Nerd Font Mono" "Regular"
```

But when changing ~/.Xresources like this

```
URxvt.font:  xft:FuraCode Nerd Font Mono:pixelsize=12
```

and running

```
xrdb -merge  ~/.Xresources
```

The next session uses the same font as i3.
Tried the same with xterm and it is working.

What am i doing wrong?

edit:

```
urxvt -fn "xft:FuraCode Nerd Font Mono:pixelsize=15"
```

is working too.

In ~/xsession-errors:
  urxvt: unable to load base fontset, please specify a valid one using -fn, aborting

Comment: don't you need a colon (`:`) after `URxvt.font`?

Comment: yes (and since resource-names can have blanks, the setting is misleading)

Comment: @mosvy that was a typo in my post, in the Xresourses it is correct

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. Running `echo 'URxvt.font:  xft:FuraCode Nerd Font Mono:pixelsize=12' | xrdb -override` will cause `urxvt` to use that font on my system. You have something else; I highly doubt that the resources were added correctly; please add the output of `xprop -root | egrep -o 'URxvt([^\\]|\\t)*'` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to Xsession(5):

*"X  resources  are  merged.   run-parts is again used, this time to identify files in the /etc/X11/Xresources directory that should be processed with ‘xrdb -merge’.  Next, if the line ‘allow-user-resources’ is present in Xsession.options, the user's $HOME/.Xresources file is merged in the same way."*

So you should make sure your *"/etc/X11/Xsession.options"* certainly have the correct entry.

I am not much an X(7) user but for those cases I run Xorg I use the old method to personalize urxvt with *"/home/user/.Xdefaults"* but the format it's a bit different than the one you  explains.

If you need here you have the correct way to set the font:

```
: cat .Xdefaults 
!rxvt
rxvt*foreground:        white
rxvt*background:        black
rxvt*cursorColor:       white
rxvt*pointerColor:      white
rxvt*borderColor:       black
rxvt*font:  -xos4-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-72-72-c-80-*-*
etcetera...
```

To get the correct name for your font you can use xfontsel(1)

P.S.: You could try to put rxvt instead of urxvt in your ~/.Xresources.

Comment: My setup does not use Xsession, but merging is done the correct. Using rxvt broke URxvt. Xdefault with Fure Code font broke too. in ~/.xsession-errors there is urxvt: unable to load base fontset, please specify a valid one using -fn, aborting

Answer (score 1):

Solved by hard coding in i3 config:

```
# start a terminal
bindsym $mod+Return exec urxvt -fn "xft:FuraCode Nerd Font Mono:style=Light:pixelsize=12"
```